# DDD - How to modify several AR (from different bounded contexts) throughout single request?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I would want expose a little scenario which is still at paper state, and which, regarding DDD principle seem a bit tedious to accomplish.

Let's say, I've an application for hosting accounts management. Basically, the application compose several bounded contexts such as Web accounts management, Ftp accounts management, Mail accounts management... each of them represented by their own AR (they can live standalone).

Now, let's imagine I want to provide a UI with an HTML form that compose one fieldset for each bounded context, for instance to update limits and or features. How should I process exactly to update all AR without breaking single transaction per request principle? Can I create a kind of "outer" AR, let's say a ClientHostingProperties AR which would holds references to other AR and update them as part of single transaction, using own repository? Or should I better create an AR that emit messages to let's listeners provided by the bounded contexts react on, in which case, I should probably think about ES?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You don't.

An aggregate is a transactional boundary, which means that if you would update multiple aggregates in one "action", you'd have to use multiple transactions. The reason for an aggregate to be equivalent to one transaction is that this allows you to guarantee consistency.

This means that you have two options:

1. You can make your aggregate larger. Then you can actually guarantee consistency, but your ability to handle concurrent requests gets worse. So this is usually what you want to avoid.
2. You can live with the fact that it's two transactions, which means you are eventually consistent. If so, you usually use something such as a process manager or a flow to handle updating multiple aggregates. In its simplest form, a flow is nothing but a simple *if this event happens, run that command* rule. In its more complex form, it has its own state.

Hope this helps

Comment: I got the point but is there no way to have one specialized AR surrounding other AR? What wrong with this approach?

Comment: It's against the definition of what an aggregate is all about. An aggregate is – by definition – a transactional boundary. If you introduce something such as a *super aggregate*, you effectively turn multiple aggregates into a single, larger one. If this is actually what you want to do, then make it explicit, and turn the aggregates into a single one. If you don't want to do this, live with eventual consistency. That's basically the two options you have. I hope this clarified things a little bit more.

Comment: @GoloRoden hey I have small followup question, what if two ARs are from different contexts? or you can't make bigger AR because current one COULD exist outside of big one. And requirements are saying no to eventual consistency?

Answer (score 1):

> How should I process exactly to update all AR without breaking single transaction per request principle?

You are probably looking for a [process manager](https://abdullin.com/post/ddd-evolving-business-processes-a-la-lokad/).

Basic sketch: persisting the details from the submitted form is a transaction unto itself (you are offered an opportunity to accrue business value; step 1 is to *capture* that opportunity).

That gives you a way to keep track of whether or not this task is "done": you compare the changes in the task to the state of the system, and fire off commands (to run in isolated transactions) to make changes.

Processes, in my mind, end up looking a lot like state machines.  These tasks are commands are done, these commands are not done, these commands have failed: now what?  and eventually reach a state where there are no additional changes to be made, and this instance of the process is "done".